iCloud Drive Resolve Version Conflicts modificationDate issue
I've encountered an issue after integrating iCloud Drive wanted to bring it to your attention.
Let me walk through the scenario:
I have two devices linked to the same account, an iPhone XR and an iPad. Here's how I create a conflict:

I initiate a text file on the online device (iPhone XR).
I record something on the offline device (iPad).
I update the file again on the online device (iPhone XR).
I switch the offline device (iPad) back online.

My expectation is that the last recorded text should be retrieved from the file that was updated on the iPhone XR since it was the latest action taken on this device.
However, upon subsequent attempts to read the file, I encounter a conflict. I aim to resolve this conflict in accordance with Apple's guidelines, referencing https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/documents_data_and_pasteboard/synchronizing_documents_in_the_icloud_environment#3743502
My approach is to compare modification dates using NSFileVersion, but strangely, I'm getting identical modification dates for both NSFileVersion.unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItem and NSFileVersion.currentVersionOfItem. Consequently, my function fails to accurately compare these dates.
Below is the snippet of code I'm using:
   private func pickLatestVersion(for documentURL: URL) -> Bool {
        guard let versionsInConflict = NSFileVersion.unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItem(at: documentURL),
              let currentVersion = NSFileVersion.currentVersionOfItem(at: documentURL) else {
            return false
        }
        let currentVersionURLDate: Date? = currentVersion.url.getAttribute(fileAttribute: .modificationDate)
        print("Current Version: ", currentVersion.modificationDate?.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .complete))
        print("Current Version URL DATE: ", currentVersionURLDate?.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .complete))
        let currentString = try? String(contentsOf: currentVersion.url, encoding: .utf8)
        print("Current String: ", currentString)
        var shouldRevert = false
        var winner = currentVersion
        for version in versionsInConflict {
            let versionURLDate: Date? = version.url.getAttribute(fileAttribute: .modificationDate)
            print("Conflict Version: ", version.modificationDate?.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .complete))
            print("Conflict Version URL DATE: ", versionURLDate?.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .complete))
            let conflictString = try? String(contentsOf: version.url, encoding: .utf8)
            print("Conflict String: ", conflictString)
            
            
            if let date1 = version.modificationDate, let date2 = currentVersion.modificationDate,
               date1 > date2 {
                winner = version
            }
        }
        if winner != currentVersion {
            do {
                try winner.replaceItem(at: documentURL)
                shouldRevert = true
            } catch {
                print("Failed to replace version: \(error)")
            }
        }
        do {
            try NSFileVersion.removeOtherVersionsOfItem(at: documentURL)
            versionsInConflict.forEach({$0.isResolved = true})
        } catch {
            print("Failed to remove other versions: \(error)")
        }
        return shouldRevert
    }

For illustrative purposes, here are the logs I receive after encountering the conflict. Additionally, I'm puzzled as to why extracting the modificationDate attribute from the conflict file URL yields one value while NSFileVersion.modificationDate returns another.
> Conflicts exist for the document file located at the file URL. Current
> Version:  Optional("Apr 15, 2024 at 5:18:21 PM GMT+3") Current Version
> URL DATE:  Optional("Apr 15, 2024 at 5:18:21 PM GMT+3") Current
> String:  Optional("Xr") Conflict Version:  Optional("Apr 15, 2024 at
> 5:18:21 PM GMT+3") Conflict Version URL DATE:  Optional("Apr 15, 2024
> at 5:18:35 PM GMT+3") Conflict String:  Optional(“iPad one)

Any insights into this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Here is also a complete Xcode project for this, which could be easily tested on devices:
iCloudFileConflict.zip
